# NodeJS jwtStrategy requires a function to retrieve jwt from requests error

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I learned tutorial from https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-1/. But I got error on this part

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done)
```

Here is the error when I  run node "server.js"

```
/home/chibi/Documents/connect/project/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:39
throw new TypeError('JwtStrategy requires a function to retrieve jwt f
          ^
TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a function to retrieve jwt from requests (see option jwtFromRequest)
at new JwtStrategy (/home/chibi/Documents/connect/project/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:39:15)
at module.exports (/home/chibi/Documents/connect/project/config/passport.js:10:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chibi/Documents/connect/project/server.js:30:29)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

What is the solution?

Comment: thanks for this post also doing this tutorial and also got this error

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think you are using 'passport-jwt' 2.0.0 which has added some breaking changes from v1.x.x used by the tutorial. In the `opts` you need to pass another option `jwtFromRequest` to tell it where to look for jwt payload.

```
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.id}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
            done(null, user);
        } else {
            done(null, false);
            // or you could create a new account
        }
    });
}));
```

Comment: For anyone who is facing the ```ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader is not a function``` error, there are breaking changes from passport-jwt 2.0 to 3.0!. You should use some other extractor like **fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken**. Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt#included-extractors a list of extractors.

Comment: @IshanThilinaSomasiri You're a lifesaver. Mods, the edit queue for this answer seems to be full. Can you please analyze the edits and add the above comment to this answer?

Answer (score 29):

From the [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt#migrating-from-2xx-to-3xx), when migrating from 2.x to 3.x using JWT you should use:

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')
```

instead of the old one:

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader()
```

Comment: I was using the validated solution before, but when I started a new project, I didn't realise that I was using 3.x, and this solutions fixed my problem!