# JwtStrategy requires a function to retrieve jwt from requests - Tried other posts already

Tags: nestjs

I have this weird issue with my code, I followed a tutorial and I've search forums for solutions, menitoning something about passport v1 and v2 versions. fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt') in my code from beginnig, but it seems to not work.

rt.strategy.ts

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport/dist';
import { ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class RtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt-refresh') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFormRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt'),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: 'rt-secret',
      passReqToCallback: true,
    });
  }

  validate(req: Request, payload: any) {
    const refreshToken = req.get('authorization').replace('Bearer', '').trim();
    return {
      ...payload,
      refreshToken,
    };
  }
}
```

at.strategy.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport/dist';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFormRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt'),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: 'at-secret',
    });
  }

  validate(payload: any) {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

It's really weird and I don't know what else to do :(

```
[Nest] 25408  - 18/02/2023, 02:16:21   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] JwtStrategy requires a function to retrieve jwt from requests (see option jwtFromRequest)
TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a function to retrieve jwt from requests (see option jwtFromRequest)
    at new JwtStrategy (D:\GitHub\gamvive_api\node_modules\passport-jwt\lib\strategy.js:55:15)
    at new MixinStrategy (D:\GitHub\gamvive_api\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\passport\passport.strategy.js:32:13)
    at new AtStrategy (D:\GitHub\gamvive_api\src\auth\strategies\at.strategy.ts:8:5)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (D:\GitHub\gamvive_api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:351:19)
    at callback (D:\GitHub\gamvive_api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:56:45)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (D:\GitHub\gamvive_api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:136:24)
    at Injector.loadInstance (D:\GitHub\gamvive_api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:61:13)
    at Injector.loadProvider (D:\GitHub\gamvive_api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:88:9)
    at D:\GitHub\gamvive_api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:49:13
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
```

I've searched for forums, they all menitone to add fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt'), but I have it from the beginning

Comment: Can you share how you're sending your request and headers?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Can't. API won't even run, this error is present as soon as I "npm run dev".

Comment: Does it answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36535956/14598976

Answer (score 0):

What version of `passport-jwt` are you using?

Can you go to your `node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/extract_jwt.js` and check the `extractors.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme` function?

It can be that you are using "wrong" `@types/passport-jwt`, meaning that the types are for the newer lib version and `fromAuthHeaderWithScheme` is in fact `undfined`

Answer (score 0):

```
MAke sure you add RtStrategy and AtStrategy to your module

@Module({
  imports: [JwtModule.register({})],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, RtStrategy, AtStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```